# Python: Plot error from two different implementations of an algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written two different implementations of an algorithm. One uses integer maths while the other uses floating point maths. The results from both are written into a file. The results are generated as 8x8 matrices. Each output 8x8 matrix corresponds to an input 8x8 matrix.

I have written a python script that reads the files containing output data of each algorithm. It calculates the error between the results of the two implementations. The error is a floating point number. I need to plot the error frequency. I guess this basically gives a histogram.

Now if I was dealing with integers and the errors were e.g -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, I could just create bin for each of these values and increment the bin value according to the error frequency encountered. Then I can plot that as a histogram. However, that is not possible here since I have the error as floating point numbers.

Floating point number maths does not give a discrete error value like the one I can get with integer maths. I mean I might get a difference of 0.1000000000 or 0.1000000001, but in reality this is happening just because of the way floating point maths works in hardware.

What is the correct approach to create bins and plot histogram in this case of floating point values in Python language?

Comment: This is not related to Python

Comment: at the end you'll have to make a reasonable assumption about the number of bins in the histogram. You can also try kernel density estimation, but you'd still need to make assumptions about kernel width.

Comment: It is also possible that just reporting median and std is enough for your purpose. For visualization purposes, boxplots could be helpful, too

Comment: This post might not be related to Python but I am using Python, I am a hardware engineer designing electronic circuits for living, software is not my domain.